# Steam ID of Games: Fixed or Random?

Tags: steam, terraria

So I'm creating a simple bat script to move Terraria Maps to a specific Dropbox Folder, and I've added a few more funcionalities than just moving the map from the Dropbox Folder to the PC folder and viceversa. One of those new funcionalities is to launch Terraria from the bat script.

Since I can't find any info on this subject, my question is: **Does the Steam ID of a game changes from user to user, or it's the same for everybody ?** (I.E My Terraria Steam ID is 105600)

It's probably a dumb question, but very useful for me (and I'm guessing for someone else too) because the script fetches that ID.

Answer (score 5):

The ID's are the same for all users on Steam.
If you take the browser link of Terraria in the Steam-Store, you can see the ID you was talking about

[http://store.steampowered.com/app/**105600**/](http://store.steampowered.com/app/105600/)

Edit: But for your script, keep in mind that Game ID's can change anytime, Steam wont promise that the ID's will be the same forever.

Comment: The likelyhood of them changing though is pretty much next to nothing.

Comment: @Gigazelle thats true